# Can I say “1kg of watermelons”

Tags: quantifiers

There are three watermelons, and each watermelon weighs 1kg. In this case, can I say “there are 1kg of watermelons”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are three watermelons, and each watermelon weighs 1kg. In this
> case, can I say “there are 1kg of watermelons”?

No. The total weight of watermelons is 3 kg. You would say "I have 3 kg of watermelons"

Answer (score -1):

No, unless they're **exceedingly** small watermelons.

"1 kg of grapes," makes sense, because you'd certainly have multiple grapes. However, your talking about watermelon *flesh*, not a whole watermelon, so ask for, "1 kg of watermelon." the watermelon flesh, like water, is not countable.

Comment: Then, should I say 3kg of watermelon?

Comment: @user0203, possibly - it depends if you're discussing one or many melons. Certainly, "30 kg of watermelons," would be acceptable. And if you're buying sliced melon, "30 kg of watermelon," might be a better choice.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - yes. the point is that when discussing fruit, vegetables, etc, we generally consider them plural if they remain whole and distinct, but uncountable/singular once processed in some way, so 10 kg of potatoes but 10 kg of mashed potato.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, yes, and 1 kg of watermelon is equivalent to mashed potatoes: you have only a piece of the whole.